# Is use of `make` meaningful when using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-tasks

When using VS Code what you can do with `make` can be done with `tasks.json` as well and `make` is not preinstalled on Windows. If you can force your team which uses various OS to use VS Code, is there any reason to use `make`?

Comment: `you can do with make can be done with tasks.json` is not true, you can't build an appliction with 100 C++ files with ONLY `tasks.json`

Comment: @rioV8 Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why do I need to elaborate, I have a project with 100 C++ files, consisting of application and several libraries that are build from that, you should show me how I could build this with `tasks.json`

Comment: I don't know how you use `make`, just let me know a part which cannot be done with `tasks.json`. I guess you use much commands to build but I'm not familiar with C++.

Comment: so if you are not familiar with C++ and make why state that make can do what tasks can do? If you have more than 1 C++ file `tasks.json` are useless. Any serious application has more than 1 C++ file, although I know a useful 0-MQ app that is just 1 C++ file. Competitive programming is not serious programming

Comment: I intend to use `make` for developing Go app with some tasks like install/update dependencies, build and clean. All of them are single command so it can be actually done with `tasks.json` in my case. Preferably I want to see your makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface, you can use either Makefiles or `tasks.json` to execute various shell scripts. With the property `dependsOn` of `tasks.json`, you can do a topological sort of tasks that Makefile also does.

There are still things that `make` does better than `tasks.json`:

1. `make` can check timestamps of files to find which files are outdated and which tasks it doesn't need to execute. Maybe you can do that using various shell scripts in `tasks.json`, but using Makefiles would be far more convenient. For very big projects with a lot of source code, this is a very great feature since you can save a lot of time instead of re-building 100s of files you didn't need to.
2. `make` contains an interface engine, supporting suffix rules and support for wildcards. I don't think `tasks.json` support that. You can probably use some extra shell scripts to achieve the same, but it won't be as neat as how `make` does it.
3. Finally, Makefiles can be run in any system that has `make`, and therefore it is independent of VS Code.

If you're working on a small/simple enough project, you can absolutely work on it without using `make`. For large projects, `make` is the sensible choice.

In my college project, we are using Makefiles. We work on VS Code so we set the `tasks.json` scripts to just use make commands with the said Makefile. You can do that as well if you like.

Comment: You completely cover all of the things I wanted to know. Totally understand, thank you so much!

Comment: @TakuyaHARA Glad to help